# Changing timer sound in Oppo devices

Tags: alarm, clock, oppo

I have an Oppo AX5 with Android 8.1.0. The clock app timer sounds like a smoke alarm.

How can I change the timer sound?

Comment: Google clock has settings specific sound for timers.

Comment: I agree. It's awful! Nearly gave me a heart attack the first time it went off. I have the Oppo A91, same story. Not having much luck on Google unfortunately.